# Not all sign up buttons are grayed out in maintenance mode

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sign-up, maintenance, read-only

When the site is in read-only mode, the 'Sign up' button in the navigation bar is grayed out because it doesn't work. Could that be extended to the button in the 'welcome anonymous user' banner?

[image: incoherent clickable/unclickable sign-up buttons]

<sub>(posted via the iOS app, apparently the API is not read-only at the moment...)</sub>

Comment: Isn't the fact that you were able to post when the site was read-only a bug too?

Comment: @GoodDeeds well, it's good to have a workaround to post extremely urgent and important questions like this one ... </sarcasm>

Comment: @GoodDeeds "*This site is currently in (mostly) read-only mode"*...

Comment: Just to clarify, by "because it doesn't work", did you mean the buttons weren't clickable at all (like the Ask Question button)?

Comment: @Justin I don't remember - it's been a while ...

Comment: No issues :) It seems the functionality has changed now. The Log in and Sign up buttons are not grayed out, but when clicked on, users are led to a "this functionality doesn't work because the site is undergoing maintenance" page. // I can confirm the specific bug you've posted has been fixed(?) as the "Sign up to join this community" banner is no longer shown on any site (as stated below).

Comment: @Justin thanks, then I'll mark it as accepted

Comment: Oops, forgot to link to some screenshots.. Here: [#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW6ef.jpg), [#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLP1I.jpg), [#3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr0Z6.jpg) & [#4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97yJI.jpg).

Comment: @Justin I guess you could add them to the accepted answer?

Comment: I was thinking of doing so, but the Sign up and Log in buttons aren't grayed out like in the screenshot in the question, so people might think it's a bug (is it?).

Comment: @Justin well, the goal of the feature request is completed: users are properly informed about the maintenance even when clicking buttons they shouldn't. I would probably have made a different choice, but then I know zip about the code base ...

Comment: I've added a screenshot to the answer. I suppose this should be [status-completed] then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We just published a package of fixes for read-only related bugs that included this one. We've decided to remove those banners from appearing altogether when the website is in read-only mode, the reasoning here being that we shouldn't invite users to register if we won't allow them to do so, seems counter-intuitive.

Thanks for reporting! We appreciate the help.

---

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

---

The <kbd>Sign up</kbd> and <kbd>Log in</kbd> buttons are clickable, and lead to a separate "[Sign up / Log in] is currently unavailable" page ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sr0Z6.jpg)).

Comment: @Glorfindel and random hero, thanks for reporting this! After seeing some screenshots we went down an internal search of why the changes didn't seem to be there. Turns out we had a problem with our Secondary build, and that's where we were running off from last weekend. A build will be triggered tonight and should fix the issue for the next time we run off of Secondary. Appreciate the help!